# Apache won't starting on Uwamp

Tags: uwamp

When I run Uwamp, Apache doesn't start but directly turns off, unlike MySQL which runs perfectly.
I tried downloading a new uwamp zip and intalled the prerequisites but nothing changed.
It never worked since I downloaded it.

Comment: Please share the (relevant) parts of the error.log in (`UwAmp\bin\apache\logs`) Also, when a product has this behaviour as yourself if it is worth investing time in it. Maybe choose another product which works OK ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The logs folder is empty and Apache won't start on Uwamp 3.1. What might be the problem source?

Comment: I installed it, only changed port settings (The line with `<VirtualHost *:###>`  I changed the default 80 to another free port number (for example 8080), and it works (only a weird error when stopping apache about 'access denied')

Answer (score 0):

I fixe the bug with install vsc++ 2012 x86 (I'm on windows 64 bits) and it's work.
If it doesn't work, you can try to launch apache in /bin/apace/bin/http.exe